# How to wait for completion of all asynchronous tasks before running final tasks

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, healthkit

I must be misunderstanding `dispatch_group` because my `dispatch_group_notify` call is running before the end of the async calls made within individual `dispatch_group_async` blocks. Here's my code:

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_group_t dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    // create operation for each HKTypeIdentifier for which we want to retrieve information
    for( NSString *hkType in typesToRetrieve){
            dispatch_group_async(dispatchGroup, queue, ^{
                     // this method runs several HK queries each with a completion block as indicated below
                    [self getDataForHKQuantity: hkType withCompletion:^(NSArray *results) {
                     // this completion blocks runs asynchronously as HK query completion block
                     // I want to runCompletionBlock only after
                     // all these processResultsArray calls have finished
                    [self processResultsArray:results];
                }];
            });
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self runCompletionCheck];
    });
```

The method `getDataForHKQuantity` in turn runs an asynchronous query to HealthKit with a completion block. I need to run `runCompletionCheck` after all these completion blocks for the HealthKit queries have run, but what is happening now is that `runCompletionCheck` is running before the code in the queries' completion blocks has run. To me that means that `dispatch_group_notify` along with `dispatch_group_async` don't work the way I need, so what am I doing wrong or what's the best way to handle this?

Overall goal: make a bunch of concurrent queries to HealthKit, run their completion blocks, then when all those completion blocks run, run a final method.

The problem is two fold. **First,** the health kit queries don't always run their completion blocks. I started by using a counter system, with a counter in the health kit queries' completion blocks. That's what told me that these completion blocks don't always run. **Second,** I don't know how many queries I am trying to run because it depends on what data sources the user has.

So, question, how can  I wait until all the completion blocks from a series of health kit queries have run before running a final method?

Answer (score 4):

Your `-getDataForHKQuantity:withCompletion:` method is asynchronous. So, through your dispatch groups you are syncing the *calls* to these methods, but not the work done in the methods themselves.

In other words, you are nesting two asynchronous calls, but syncing only the first level through you dispatch groups.

You'll need to come up with a different strategy for controlling your program flow.

Two examples:

### 1. Using Semaphores (blocking)

Some time ago, I used semaphores for a similar task, not sure it's the best strategy, but in your case it would go sth like:

```
semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

for( NSString *hkType in typesToRetrieve)
{
    [self getDataForHKQuantity: hkType withCompletion:^(NSArray *results) {

        // register running method here

        [self processResultsArray:results];

        if (isLastMethod) // need to keep track of concurrent methods running
        {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        }
    }];
}

// your program will wait here until all calls to getDataForHKQuantity complete
// so you could run the whole thing in a background thread and wait for it to finish
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

### 2. Using dispatch_group

```
dispatch_group_t serviceGroup = dispatch_group_create();

for( NSString *hkType in typesToRetrieve)
{
    dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);

    [self getDataForHKQuantity: hkType withCompletion:^(NSArray *results) {

        [self processResultsArray:results];
        dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);
    }];
}

dispatch_group_notify(serviceGroup,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    // Won't get here until everything has finished
});
```

Also check [this link](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/) for further info.

Comment: I wouldn't use semaphores, as they block and you may be on the main thread. You still may use dispatch_group but you have to use dispatch_group_enter() and dispatch_group_leave(). You have to enter before the async call, then leave in the competion block.